# Como gerar pdf de uma página do Django com gráficos, imagens e textos (resultado de um assessment)

Tags: python, django, pdf

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Django e preciso exibir o resultado de um assessment (teste) que terá textos, imagens e gráficos. Inicialmente fiz esta parte utilizando o Chart.js com base neste exemplo: https://youtu.be/1OL5n06kO_w

O problema é que também preciso da opção de gerar um pdf desta página de resultado do teste, mantendo a formatação e gráficos. Consigo gerar pdf com imagens e texto, porém perde a formatação do texto e não exibe os gráficos do Chart.js.

Preciso mudar a forma de gerar o gráfico, abandonando o Chart.js ou o problema está na forma como estou tentando gerar o pdf através do pisa.pisaDocument conforme abaixo:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

Comment: Vale mencionar que tentei várias formas diferentes de gerar o pdf. Por isso me questiono se não deveria mudar a forma como gero os gráficos.

Comment: Crie página com o que precisa com graficos imagens texto no padrão que necessita e use o https://weasyprint.org/  ...Ele monta o pdf usando as instruções do css html

Answer (score -2):

so falta adicionar `result.seek(0)` em baixo da variavel `pdf` como no exemplo a baixo

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    result.seek(0)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```